# Dockerize project Azure Devops (microsoft tfs local) without DockerFile or automatic create Dockerfile

Tags: azure-devops, devops

Hi I used Microsoft Azure DevOps (version 2021) for CICD
and my project successfully build Image Docker
but one Programmer changed DockerFile and Program Run with Another Library

Now I am looking for a solution that DockerFile can not change Except for
myself or create Automatic on CICD Azure or Build Project Without
DockerFile

Thanks for Help

Comment: This is a process and communication problem, not a technical problem. If someone shouldn't be modifying certain files, *tell them* what they shouldn't be doing, and then don't approve PRs that contain changes to those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a branch policy to your target branch, then any change cannot commit to the target branch directly, but only via pull request. You can set approver as yourself, and set it as required, then you can approve/deny changes from others.
Please refer to official doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops) for the details.
screenshot as below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Glad to know it's resloved, did you use the suggestion i provided?If yes, you can mark it as answer then it could help others as well. If not, would you mind sharing the details here？ Thanks!